# How do you change the name of a Label using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `UserForm` which contains many `labels` and `textboxes` inside them. As a part of my Requirement, I need to go and change my label name using vba.

I couldn't find help on the Internet about this. So if somebody knows, Please kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Why is the question down-voted? Just to avoid confusion, the question was not about changing label content but about changing the label name something like from 'label1' to 'Lbl1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the name of an object at run-time. You have to do that at design time using the property pane.